# How to create thumbnail view for iPad?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ipad

I want a tutorial for help me to create a table view thumbnail like this.

[image: thumbnail view]

I use UItableView to implement this view and try to custom UITableViewCell

but UITableViewCell can't support

anyone can sugess me

thank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need all the features of a table view, and the number of thumbnails isn't large, you can just make the thumbnails as image buttons inside a UIView inside a UIScrollView.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, a `UITableView` might well be a good starting point.

I think I would create a custom `UITableViewCell` with four horizontal images. The rest is pretty much the same as some of Apple's sample code.

Comment: OK, I will find simple code from Apple, thank